# Google Cloud Credit Card Verification Issue - Temporary Charge Not Showing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, verification, credit-card, billing

I'm currently setting up my Google Cloud Platform (GCP) account and facing an issue with the credit card verification process.

After entering my card details, GCP informs me that they will make a small, temporary charge to my account for verification, which I'm supposed to confirm. However, my credit card provider (Visa) states that they can only see a transaction request from Google but no actual charge since the amount is 0.00€. They mentioned that due to the zero amount, they can't generate or see any verification code.

I've been waiting for a few days now, but the situation remains the same. I've also tried to get in touch with Google's support, but I haven't been able to get the help I need since I'm currently on the free tier of GCP.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue? Is there a workaround for this situation or some other way to complete the verification process? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your case the best way to address this is to contact the sales support for GCP.[1] You may retry the verification process or check your payment method(credit card) if the issue persists. Hope this helps.

[1]

https://cloud.google.com/contact